# Is there any way in any of the Stack Overflow communities to save notes?

Tags: discussion

I see a lot of posts and follow the interesting questions in the community. Is there any way I can store some kind of notes for the questions and the answers so that I can easily search through all the notes whenever required?

Comment: No. The general consensus is that features like this (which are complex and expensive to build and maintain on a site this massive in scale, while not adding anything to the site's core value nor earnings for the business behind it) are best implemented on the user's side, using one of the many utilities available (site annotation browser plugins, 3rd party utilities, note-storing apps...)

Comment: Why so negativity? I just asked a question and I don't k own the stuff you have mentioned just mention the link if you find any. I really appreciate that, may be this is the reason a beginner afraid to ask the question

Comment: Where do you see negativity in my response?

Answer (score 1):

You can favorite individual questions which allows you to find them again.

I suppose you could also use your profile description to store notes. This is public though and really not what its meant for.